# Use existing image sizes for WooCommerce

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, images

I've built a theme and have set the following image dimensions via functions.php:

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 1064, 347, true ); // Upload @ 2128(W) x 708(H)
add_image_size( 'standard', 352, 235, true ); // Upload @ 704(W) x 470(H)
add_image_size( 'gallery', 750, 500, true ); // Upload @ 1500(W) x 1000(H)
```

I use [this script](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ensuring-your-theme-has-retina-support--wp-33430) to push out 2 versions of the image for retina displays.

I would like to use the image size `'standard'` for my catalog images and `'gallery'` for the single product image.

Is there a way to disable the WooCommerce image sizes via functions.php and use the ones I have already created?

I've tried customising the image sizes via Settings > Products, but it doesn't work with the retina script I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `single_product_large_thumbnail_size` filter for Single Product page.

something like:

```
function custom_product_large_thumbnail_size()  {
    return 'gallery';
}
add_filter('single_product_large_thumbnail_size', 'custom_product_large_thumbnail_size');
```

Comment: That works, thank you. Handy document here to find the other filters: http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html.

Answer (score -1):

You have to regenerate all the images with the specified sizes and for that you can use Regenerate Thumbnails plugin from wordpress. you can download it from http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/